# Youtube videoId variable?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use a variable in the videoId part of the Youtube API... I am pretty new to JavaScript, what I would like to do is make a list of videos and call one randomly to videoId. I am trying to get it to work with one video first.

```
var test = 'FO7Re3mKNj4';
```

and then calling it with

```
videoId: 'test[index]',
```

This does not seem to work, Thanks for reading.

Comment: Test is not `object` or `array` to access using `key`

Comment: How should I go about fixing it then...

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: `var test = ['FO7Re3mKNj4', 'another_id', 'another_id2'];` When test is array you can use `videoId: test[index],` - without quotes.

Comment: @MoshFeu, _'And without quotes'_

Comment: @RayonDabre You are right. Updated..

Comment: Okay, this is what I got now... Seems to have disappeared... http://pastebin.com/1GCQxjPm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong is single quotes in the videoId.

The complete solution would be like:

1. This should be the syntax for the array:

```
    var test = ['xyz', 'abc', 'def'];
```

2. No quotes required.

```
    videoId: test[index]
```

Comment: I changed it... And the player seems to have disappeared completely... http://pastebin.com/1GCQxjPm

Comment: I don't think you have declared any index in it yet. Please set the value of index as var index = 0; at the starting. Once it starts working, since you need to play the video randomly you can replace the value of index with the random function in javascript.

Comment: How to I add a random function, this is my first time working with JavaScript.

Comment: Use var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (videos.length)); to get  the random value. It will randomly select any value between 0 and videos.length - 1 and put it at the videoId of the player.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it working! :D Been messing around this all morning. Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing, how do I make it play the next random video when the current one ends. I got it to alert to the user that a video has ended but how do I make it load another video?

Comment: I think you cannot do it one the same player. Till now what I have done is destroy the current player and make a new one in the onPlayerStateChange function.This is what I added in the function:
if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          player.destroy();
          player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: videos[index],
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
        }